# find a surface area of paraboloid $z=1-2x^2-3y^2$ that lies inside the cylinder $16x^2+36y^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

I tried find the surface area using the formula:

$A(S) = $$\int \int \sqrt{1+(\frac{dz}{dx})^2+(\frac{dz}{dy})^2} $$ $

and I got to:

\begin{align*}
A(S) &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+16x^2+36y^2}rdrd\theta \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+1}rdrd\theta \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{2}rdrd\theta 
\end{align*}

and I get $2\sqrt{2}\pi$ as my final answer after solving the integral.

Is this correct?

Comment: No it is not. You can't substitute the equation for the ellipse when you are integrating  inside of the ellipse. Not to mention your bounds are completely wrong because this is an ellipse, not a circle.

Comment: I also tried parametrizing  to get $\sqrt{1+4[4r^2cos^2\theta+9r^2sin^2\theta]}$ but I wasn't sure if this was right and if so what to do from here

Comment: Use a different coordinate system, other wise your bounds will be a mess. Right now, the equation of that ellipse in polar is given by $$r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{16\cos^2\theta+36\sin^2\theta}}$$ that is a mess. Come up with something that looks like polar, but scaled so that your bounds are constants.

Comment: Also respond to the question you had yesterday.

Comment: That means upvote, accept an answer, or comment on the people who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=4x$ and $v=6y$ to write the equation  $16x^2+36y^2=1$ as $u^2+v^2=1$ and integral as,

$$A(S) = \int_{S} \sqrt{1+16x^2+36y^2}dxdy$$
$$=\frac1{24}\int_{S} \sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}dudv$$
$$= \frac1{24}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+r^2}rdrd\theta$$
$$=\frac\pi{12} \cdot \frac13 (1+r^2)^{3/2}\bigg|_0^1 = \frac\pi{36}(2\sqrt2-1)$$

Comment: why is the $\frac{1}{24}$ taken out?

Comment: @ph-quiett - because $dxdy=\frac1{24}dudv$ resulting from the variable changes $u=4x$ and $v=6y$.